# Can I fill a vector with an image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, shapes, photoshop-effects

Really new to this so sorry if anything seems dumb!

I've got a vector that I'd really like to replace the colour with glitter. Is there any way to replace the colour in the vector with a jpeg image of the glitter colour?

Hope that makes snes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you certainly can!

It's called a vector mask, when you use a path as the mask.

Draw a vector path with the pen tool, and click *Layer > Vector Mask > Current Path*

Example:

[image]

Or

If you already have a vector shape on its own layer, put the image on a layer above and <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd>+click between the two layers to clip the image to the shape below.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's called a mask. You have a layer with the glitter image, another layer with the vector shape, and with these you can create a mask:

- https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html
- https://youtu.be/Y1I9ahx_hYs?t=203